# Hello, I'm just learning. Can someone help me to understand how this code knows where to put the X. I'm just not seeing it. Thanks

Tags: python, nested-lists

```
row1 = ["⬜️","️⬜️","️⬜️"]
row2 = ["⬜️","⬜️","️⬜️"]
row3 = ["⬜️️","⬜️️","⬜️️"]
map = [row1, row2, row3]
print(f"{row1}\n{row2}\n{row3}")
position = input("Where do you want to put the treasure? ")

horz = int(position[0])
vert = int(position[1])

### This is what I don't understand ###
selected = map[vert - 1]
selected[horz - 1] = "X"
###

print(f"{row1}\n{row2}\n{row3}")
```

I used 23 as the input:
I understand some of this I just don't understand how it knows what row.

There is the list map
Then the nested lists row1 row2 and row3 inside the list map.
The input is stored in vert and horz.

That's where my understanding ends. The rows are stacked so how does it know where the X goes in row3 in the 2nd position.

Comment: Okay, so there's a line of code that says `selected = map[vert - 1]`. It seems, from what you've written, that you already understand what `map` means here. What do you think will be the result of `vert - 1`? Do you understand what the `[]` do at this point in the code? Therefore, if you put those steps together, do you see what the result will be for `map[vert - 1]`? And then, the entire line says that `selected` should be a name for that result - right? And then, follow the same logical steps to understand the next line. **At what point in this process is the confusing part**?

Comment: "The rows are stacked" I can't understand what you mean by this, or why it causes a problem for your own understanding of the code. " so how does it know where the X goes in row3 in the 2nd position." Well, it doesn't necessarily mean that, right? It will depend on what input values were stored, right?

Comment: Use a source debugger to view the variables as you step through the code or simply add print statements after each line to understand how the variables change.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel "The rows are stacked" - I mean there are 3 rows, then a new line, 3 more rows, then a new line. Then 3 more rows.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I've done that, when I print out selected after selected[horz - 1] = "X" - it shows me two rows with the x in the center col bottom row (so two rows vs. three). Then when I print the final line - print(f"{row1}\n{row2}\n{row3}") - I get the correct answer. So I don't understand how we get from the vert/horz input to the "X" in the correct spot.

Comment: "it shows me two rows" Are you sure? "with the x in the center col bottom row" Isn't that where it's supposed to be? "Then when I print the final line - print(f"{row1}\n{row2}\n{row3}") - I get the correct answer." How is that different from what you saw before? "So I don't understand how we get from the vert/horz input to the "X" in the correct spot." How is it in a different spot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the code slightly to make the cells indicate the number to access it and make the added `print` statements easier to follow:

```py
row1 = ['11','21','31']
row2 = ['12','22','32']
row3 = ['13','23','33']
map = [row1, row2, row3]
print(f'{row1}\n{row2}\n{row3}')
position = input('Where do you want to put the treasure? ')

horz = int(position[0])
print(f'{horz=}')
vert = int(position[1])
print(f'{vert=}')

### This is what I don't understand ###
selected = map[vert - 1]
print(f'{selected=}')
selected[horz - 1] = 'XX'
print(f'{selected=}')
###

print(f'{row1}\n{row2}\n{row3}')
```

Output (with comments):

```
['11', '21', '31']
['12', '22', '32']
['13', '23', '33']
Where do you want to put the treasure? 23
horz=2                                       # horz selects the column
vert=3                                       # vert selects the row
selected=['13', '23', '33']                  # selected refers to row3 (map[2])
selected=['13', 'X', '33']                   # change selected (map[2][1])
['11', '21', '31']
['12', '22', '32']
['13', 'XX', '33']
```

In Python, variables are names of objects.  `selected = map[vert - 1]` where `vert = 3` makes `selected` becomes another name for the item in `map[2]` which is the *same* item referred to by the name `row3`.

`selected[horz - 1] = 'XX'` where `horz = 2` changes `row3[1]` to `XX`.  Since that same item is in in the `map`, the change is reflected there as well.